# alfresco-maven-plugin; truezip issues to pre-AMP a WAR

Tags: maven, alfresco

I'm really struggling with the alfresco-maven-plugin and looking for some help.  The usecase is to pre-apply the AMPs to the alfresco and share WAR's (version 4.2.f) before deploying to the system related to file permission issues running the apply_amp.sh in a secured environment.

I've tried the following, both 1.1.1 and 2.0.0 versions, both with the associated parent alfresco-sdk-parent and without (NOTE: Without the parent is preferred, as we have company parent POM's for distribution and other reasons)

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.alfresco.maven.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>alfresco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install-amps</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <ampLocation>${project.build.directory}/amps</ampLocation>
                         <warLocation>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-war</warLocation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Consistently getting the error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/schlichtherle/truezip/fs/FsSyncExceptionBuilder
```

I've added as dependencies, and as plugin dependencies, the truezip, truezip-file, truezip-driver-file, truezip-driver-zip, truezip-swing, trying truezip versions from 6.X to 7.8.1, tried explicity listing the alfresco-mmt versions 4.2.f to 5.0.c (the 5.0.x seems to pre-bundle, but is not helping with the maven plugin).

Any guidance please?

EDIT: The answer provided below for this question asked over 2 years ago was answered related to an incorrect version of maven. A possible duplicate [TrueZip: NoClassDefFoundError (but for shutdown hook only?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267536/truezip-noclassdeffounderror-but-for-shutdown-hook-only) was detected was asked later and does not provide an answer/does not solve the problem; Note this question is considered 'answered' and resolved.

Comment: The latest Alfresco Maven AMP plugin version looks to be [3.0.4](https://maven.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/org/alfresco/maven/plugin/maven-amp-plugin/3.0.4/), what happens if you try that?

Comment: The scenario above is not to create an AMP (what the alfresco maven AMP plugin does), it is taking an already built AMP(s) and applying them to the Alfresco / Share WAR (this is how alfresco supports extensions).

Comment: Why not just run the mmt tool directly then?

Comment: To automate the creation of the fully applied WAR via a build server (Jenkins).

Comment: So have your jenkins job run the mmt tool as part of the build job? Or am I missing something?

Comment: same problem here! http://stackoverflow.com/q/29511318/1879409

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TrueZip: NoClassDefFoundError (but for shutdown hook only?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267536/truezip-noclassdeffounderror-but-for-shutdown-hook-only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were using an unsupported Maven version (in fact the Alfresco SDK 2.0.0 requires Maven 3.2.5 and above, see http://docs.alfresco.com/sdk2.0/tasks/alfresco-sdk-install-maven.html).

This explains why you are seeing this problem which instead does not exist in properly tested configurations.

Will close the related https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-sdk/issues/265 as well.

Comment: thanks for looking into this, and confirmed (the maven version required was not in place at the time, but is now).

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I did was:

Checkout 2.0.1-SNAPSHOT from here as of 3/9/2015:
https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-sdk

Using maven 3.0.5, jdk7, change plugins/alfresco-maven-plugin/pom.xml, change from version 3.2 to this version of the maven-plugin-plugin entry so it would actually compile the new version of the alfresco-maven-plugin:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <!-- <version>3.2</version> <executions> <execution> <id>generated-helpmojo</id> 
                <goals> <goal>helpmojo</goal> </goals> </execution> </executions> -->


        </plugin>
```

Update in my project the 2.0.1-SNAPSHOT of alfresco-maven-plugin and it works as expected (no alfresco-sdk parent pom neeeded).

New WAR with the AMP's pre-applied can be checked from downloading or copying the alfresco-mmt jar and using:

```
java -jar alfresco-mmt.jar list ${project}/target/${newalfresco}.war
```

Trackers until it gets resolved: https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-sdk/issues/265, https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-sdk/issues/266