# Alfresco Maven SDK - fails if module version string ends with "-SNAPSHOT"

Tags: maven, alfresco

So I created an amp project, both repo and share, and every time I try to build or run the project it fails with:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/schlichtherle/truezip/fs/FsSyncExceptionBuilder
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsManager.sync(FsManager.java:99)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsSyncShutdownHook$Hook.run(FsSyncShutdownHook.java:93)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsSyncExceptionBuilder
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 2 more
```

pom.xml

```
<project [...]>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.someco</groupId>
    <artifactId>someco-repo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>someco-repo AMP project</name>
    <packaging>amp</packaging>
    [...]
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.alfresco.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>alfresco-sdk-parent</artifactId>                       
        <version>1.1.1</version> // same with 1.1.0
    </parent>
```

Changing the module version from `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` to `1.0.0` works, but then I cannot work with snapshots (or at least identify them as `-SNAPSHOT`).

Any ideas?

Comment: Just as a test, what happens if you use `alfresco-sdk-parent` version `1.1.0` instead - does it behave then?

Comment: same with `alfresco-sdk-parent` version `1.1.0`

Answer (score 3):

This should actually work. So I wonder if there's something weird in your env. Any chance you can delete the local copy of that library (`~/.m2/repository/de/schlichterle/truezip`) and retry?

I wonder if you have a corrupted version.

Sounds weird though that it works when you change the version...

Comment: Thats the problem, I deleted my local repo many times. But if you say It should work, and for you it is working, I think there is something wrong with my env, as you suggested. Maybe because I build the project on my second hard drive? Thank you for your answer! **EDIT** Reinstalled mave, changed local repo to default location (user directory) but same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.

I had at one point run maven as root.
I tried removing `~/.m2/repository/de/schlichterle/truezip`. This did not help.

I then removed the target directory, which had some files in it owned by the root user. I don't fully understand why this fixed it, but it did.

After running maven again, the `~/.m2/repository/de/schlichterle/truezip` directory still does not exist, but apparently it is not needed as everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

When the mapping specified in `file-mapping.properties` is incorrect (not parsable by alfresco maven) then throws this error.

I am not sure why it is not able to parse the mapping.
But it throws error on:

```
web/=/
```

but not on:

```
/web/=/
```

Comment: and this error only occures if in the maven pom.xml `project.version` is declared as `SNAPSHOT` ? So if I use non-snapshot versions I can't release with maven (no SNAPSHOT version in agregator) and otherwise I cant even build it? Are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

The error log says:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

That means that there is a missing class on your code. You're using Alfresco, then, it means that you have missing dependencies. Jeff Pott's tutorials are a little deprecated now.

You need to add to your `pom.xml` file, dependencies for `truezip`, `truezip-driver` and `truezip-file`. Then, re-run and it works.

Comment: Please create issues or pull requests in the tutorial project if you find issues. The tutorial is intended to be up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [TrueZIP Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/truezip/truezip-maven-plugin/usage.html) dependency and its [drivers](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.schlichtherle.truezip) into your `pom.xml` file, e.g.

```
...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>truezip-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>de.schlichtherle.truezip</groupId>
      <artifactId>truezip-driver-file</artifactId>
      <version>7.7.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>de.schlichtherle.truezip</groupId>
       <artifactId>truezip-kernel</artifactId>
      <version>7.7.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>de.schlichtherle.truezip</groupId>
      <artifactId>truezip-driver-zip</artifactId>
      <version>7.7.9</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
...
```

For further debugging, try adding `-X` flag for your `mvn` command.

Comment: 2 years old post lol, but shouldn't the alfresco maven plugin add the dependency?

Comment: @Pali I'm not using alfresco plugin as far as I know, however I had same problem minute ago with missing class and adding the above dependency helped.